# How do I open an Electron app from the command line?

Tags: command-line, electron, command-line-interface, cross-platform, electron-builder

### Question

---

I want to open a installed electron app from the Command prompt. Similar to Visual Studio Code. Typing `code` opens VScode.

How to do something like that? I also want to provide custom arguments when opening from CLI. Example:-

```bash
printapp --option1=foo --option2
```

Then, in the app I would use those to perform different tasks. Is this possible? I want it to be cross-platform? It should not have .exe extensions. I want it to be like VScode. It should **not** be something like this:-

```bash
printapp.exe --options
```

### Other References

---

Take a look at https://hyper.is. It also has a CLI to open the app and do tasks. I want something like `hyper` or `VScode`. Even `atom` has something similar like this.

### Other possibilities

---

If opening a app from the command line is impossible in electron,
is there a way to bundle a CLI with a app using `electron-builder` (I would bundle a Node JS CLI with the app and when the user installs my app, they could use the GUI / CLI, without installing the CLI separately. Something like `hyper` I mentioned above)?

If possible, I would use the extra files option in `electron-builder` and move the CLI to the resources folder and set the PATH variable. But,

1. It may not be cross-platform
2. How to set the PATH variable when installing a app? (I don't know macros)

---

### **Any method to open the app from the CLI which is cross-platform is appreciated.**

Comment: I think this is possible.

Comment: 1 year later and still no reply